# Limit the number of digits in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have such a regex:

```
'(?:\$|сум)(\040)?(\d+)|(\d+)(\040)?(?:\$|сум)'
```

It matches the following strings:

```
$23
23$
1000сум
сум1000
сум 1000
1000 сум
```

I want to limit the number of digits in this regex to 8.

Tried this:

```
'(?:\$|сум)(\040)?(\d{, 8})|(\d{, 8})(\040)?(?:\$|сум)'
```

It stopped matching anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `\d{0,8}`?

Comment: @tobias_k yes I did. [Link to editor](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5C%24%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC)(%5C040)%3F(%5Cd%7B0%2C%208%7D)%7C(%5Cd%7B0%2C%208%7D)(%5C040)%3F(%3F%3A%5C%24%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC)&test_string=15000%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\d{, 8}
```

Means nothing .Engine will match it literally and so your regex failed.

Use

```
\d{0,8}
```

No spaces inside `{}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read somewhere that even {, 8} was possible to set the maximum. Actually, I even tried {1, 8}. My problem was in a space inside `{}`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 15):

The `{}` has three form:

- `{N}` for a fixed number of time
- `{M,}` for at least M times
- `{N,M}`for between N and M times.

If you use the last one, the minimum is mandatory.

Change your regex to `\d{1,8}` to match between 1 and 8 times a digit

Starting with 1 as you were using + which is a shortcut for `{1,}`

Comment: I read somewhere that even {, 8} was possible to set the maximum. Actually I even tried {1, 8}. My real problem was the whitespace. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to talk about the whitespace, but as @vks already stated it I didn't update :) Just left my answer for the 1 at start as you were using +

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at what [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cV3eT9/2) says:

[image]

You can use the `{1,8}` limiting quantifier that will match 1 to 8 digits. I see there must be at least 1 since you have `+` in your original regex.

```
^(?:(?:\$|сум)(\040)?(\d{1,8})|(\d{1,8})(\040)?(?:\$|сум))$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV3eT9/1)

From the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

> The syntax is `{min,max}`, where `min` is zero or a positive integer
>   number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer
>   equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches.
>   If the comma is present but `max` is omitted, the maximum number of
>   matches is infinite. So `{0,1}` is the same as `?`, `{0,}` is the same as `*`,
>   and `{1,}` is the same as `+`. Omitting both the comma and max tells the
>   engine to repeat the token exactly `min` times.

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify lower bound like `(\d{0,8})`.

Besides some regex dialects do not allow whitespace after comma in `{0,8}` construction.

Comment: Did not help. Please see [this](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5C%24%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC)(%5C040)%3F(%5Cd%7B0%2C%208%7D)%7C(%5Cd%7B0%2C%208%7D)(%5C040)%3F(%3F%3A%5C%24%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC)&test_string=15000%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: It didn't help because of whitespace after comma.

Comment: Yes, whitespace was my real problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Also specify the lower limit

`(?:\$|сум)(\040)?(\d{1,8})|(\d{1,8})(\040)?(?:\$|сум)`

This would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a lower limit as well.

```
(?:\$|сум)(\040)?(\d{0,8})|(\d{0,8})(\040)?(?:\$|сум)
```

You can see a [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dQ0oP9/1)