# Google sheets - how to extract numbers starting with a specific letter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a google sheet that reads

```
Purchased on October 14, 2021 Selling  price:11250 Name #72894044
```

Is there a way to pull all 8-string numbers starting with #, but ignore everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `REGEXTRACT` function as such:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(X, "(#\d{8})")` where X is your input.

The pair of brackets `(...)` captures the first group.
Then it checks for the `#` specifically.
Followed by checking for any digits `\d`,
And checks it for x number of times `{x}`.

It's also good to take note that there are multiple ways of defining `{...}` which you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776761/11737429).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-FIND("#",A2)))
```

**Sheet result**

[image: sheet result after using the formula]

**Explanation**

The formula returns the location of the `#` character by using `FIND` and afterwards it calculates the number of characters after `#` by making the subtraction and by using `LEN`. Afterwards, `RIGHT` returns the substring consisting of your desired value. `ARRAYFORMULA` is used considering the fact that you may have multiple entries which need the same formula applied to them.

**Reference**

- [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081);
- [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126);
- [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087);
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275).